# I have issues in unit testing angular component where ngOnInit function has to initialize async functions

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

this is the code inside Component.ts, ngOnInit function, I think this calls other apis (which takes time) and then initializes it:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.identifyTransaction();
      await this.queryData();
      await this.validateUser();
      this.initializeOptions();
      this.determineDefaultValues();
      this.initializeFormGroup();
      this.subscriptionManager();
      if(this.isRework){
        // pre-load pre-requisite data
        this.loadSyncSharePointData();
        await this.onContinue();
      }
      this.toShowComponent = true;
    } catch (error) {
      this.errorHandler(error);
    }
  }
```

this is my spec.ts file:

```
it('should create the component', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(Component, 'testNgOnInit');
    Component.testNgOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(Component).toBeTruthy();

    print(transactionService.isOpenTransaction);
    print(Component.isRework);
  }));
```

this is the error when I run test:
[image: error when i run test]

What I am really trying hard to explain is that i think when i run my test I think it doesn't wait for all the components to be rendered that's why this error pops up. I'm new to automated testing so I'm not very familiar with these problems. Thank you.

I tried creating a separate function called testNgOnInit inside Component.ts that initializes the same code inside ngOnInit and running it on the spec.ts file but still renders the same error:

```
public async testNgOnInit(): Promise<void>{
    try {
      await this.identifyTransaction();
      await this.queryData();
      await this.validateUser();
      this.initializeOptions();
      this.determineDefaultValues();
      this.initializeFormGroup();
      this.subscriptionManager();
      if(this.isRework){
        // pre-load pre-requisite data
        this.loadSyncSharePointData();
        await this.onContinue();
      }
      this.toShowComponent = true;
    } catch (error) {
      this.errorHandler(error);
    }
  }
```